# While updating my data is not getting update - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8

While updating, my data is not getting updated. Below is my code.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required'
        ]);

        $employee = empl::find($id);
            //dd($employee); Working
            //echo $id; exit; Showing id
            $employee->first_name = $request->firstname;
            $employee->last_name = $request->lastname;
            $employee->email = $request->email;
            $employee->phone = $request->phone;
            $employee->save();
            return redirect(route('home'))->with('successMsg', 'Data updated successfully');
    }
```

I can see that dd(model) and echo $id are working

But in the log file I can see null in where column. Below is the reference

```
[2021-02-25 13:52:26] local.INFO: 4.12  
[2021-02-25 13:52:26] local.INFO: update `empls` set `first_name` = ?, `last_name` = ?, `email` = ?, `phone` = ?, `empls`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` is null  
[2021-02-25 13:52:26] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'Test F name',
  1 => 'Test L name',
  2 => 'test@gmail.com',
  3 => '94452114781',
  4 => '2021-02-25 13:52:26',
)
```

Comment: Can you show the middleware?

Comment: Can you show what is `empl` here and what is `find` method of it ?

Comment: protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,, ---- I have posted first few lines from my middleware since this comments box is not allowing to post full

Answer (score 0):

So I've gotten this error while beging to learn Laravel, I'm sorry but your code seem totally correct, the dd's prove that, I've switched to this method and it works with the same params. So try this and it should work:

```
    $employee = empl::find($id);
    $employee->update([
                 'first_name' => $request->get('firstname'),
                 'last_name' => $request->get('lastname'),
                 'email' => $request->get('email'),
                 'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
             ]);

    return redirect(route('home'))->with('successMsg', 'Data updated successfully');
```

Again sorry for the lack of explanation on why your code doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks for your support. But this error as - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
Add [first_name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\empl].

Comment: Oh great, so that means that the update should work. Now just go to the App/Models/empl and add protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
    ];

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That error is fixed. But the data is not getting updated. Not sure why I am getting null for id in where. The log file says as - [2021-03-02 13:46:06] local.INFO: 7.61  
[2021-03-02 13:46:06] local.INFO: update `empls` set `first_name` = ?, `last_name` = ?, `email` = ?, `phone` = ?, `empls`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` is null  
[2021-03-02 13:46:06] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 'Monika 5',
  1 => 'Testing 5',
  2 => 'monika5@gmail.com',
  3 => '1223544789 5',
  4 => '2021-03-02 13:46:06',
)

Comment: I have an idea on why this may be. In your migration for empls is the ID set as `$table->increments('id');` or `$table->id();`? I recommend changing it to increments, that may be causing the issue.

Comment: Can you please suggest in which file I need to change. I am new to Laravel. Thank you.

Comment: In your project folder go like this: database->migrations->(numbers)_create_empls_table.php . If you have set everything up correctly as I hope you have it should be like this.

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empls', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('Id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
   -- I am having these code already. I changed 'bigIncrements' to 'increments' and tried. But same issue. Not sure what I did wrong. I have placed my source here https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bh7jtfqph0vxgo/03032021.rar?dl=0
    Thanks for your help

Comment: The last thing you can try is to pass the $Id var without the route, so just put a hidden input in your blade, bellow the @crfs, like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $empls->id }}" class="form-control">` and take out the {id} from the route and the update method and try `$empls= empls::find($request->get('id'));`

Comment: Thanks for your time and support, In that 'find' step I am getting id. Could you please refer the line '//echo $id; exit; Showing id' from my first post. So I understand that may be somewhere else I am having issues. So I shared my code via drop box. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $inputs = $request->except('_token', '_method', 'updated_at');
    $employee= empl::find($id);
    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value){
        $employee->$key = $value;
    }
    $employee->save();

   return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I am getting error as - Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'firstname' in 'field list' (SQL: update `empls` set `email` = test@gmail.com, `firstname` = Test f name, `lastname` = Test l name, `empls`.`updated_at` = 2021-02-25 16:19:26 where `id` is null). My column names are like first_name, last_name and so unknown column name. But not sure why id is still null